# Group by two columns and count

Tags: sql, count, group-by

Say I have a table Order that looks like this:

```
:price
:payment_option_id
:created_at
```

Right now, I am able to get all the units that have been sold (each row is considered a unit) for each payment_option_id, by doing this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Order WHERE payment_option_id = 3
SELECT count(*) FROM Order WHERE payment_option_id = 4
SELECT count(*) FROM Order WHERE payment_option_id = ...
```

However, now I would like to get (if it's possible in one query) all the units that have been sold by each day, so that I could report something like:

7th of July:
-Units with payment_option_id 1: 4 units 
-Units with payment_option_id 2: 0 units

8th of July:
Units with payment_option_id 1: 12 units
...

What would be a way to get this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use comma seperated items on group by as follows:

```
SELECT count(*), created_at FROM Order GROUP BY payment_option_id, created_at
```

Comment: This is cool, but then how would I know from which date is each of the returned count(*)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    Created_at,
    payment_option_id,
    COUNT(*) payment_option_id_num
from
    [Order]
group by Created_at, payment_option_id
```